# Installing some applications have inconsistant theming in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, themes

I prefer the light theme for Ubuntu UI, but some applications just look better in dark mode. Many applications however, don't have a dark mode settings option, e.g. Gnome Boxes, Gnome Connections, Amberol, etc., and don't have any theming options. What puzzles me is on different systems with identical configurations, these applications will either start in dark mode or light mode after first launch after installing them. What is the determining factor on whether they will launch in dark or light mode? And is there a workaround to force an application to use dark mode?

Comment: In linux you have not only one graphics framework, each with its own config (QT in several versions, GTK in several versions, etc.). It is up to the developer of the application which one to choose. Please help the developer of each application to implement what you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

So I have learned how to overwrite any applications default theme by starting it from the command line using `GTK_THEME=<theme-name> <application>` But as far as making it persistent, other than using a global theme, it seems to be impossible to achieve. I have tried adding the environment argument to the application's .desktop file, but that does not work on Ubuntu 22.04